# llvm metadata transformation pass

Tags: llvm

I have a toolchain of two passes. First one, is a transformation pass that should add metadata to some structures (instructions/variables) and the second pass is an analyzing pass which needs to access the added metadata. The problem is with my adding metadata transformation pass. There might be two problems(or both):

First, maybe I don't add correctly metadata.

```
    LLVMContext& C = myInstruction->getContext();
    MDNode* N = MDNode::get(C, MDString::get(C, "add info"));
    myInstruction->setMetadata("important", N);
    errs()<<"\n"<<cast<MDString>(myInstruction->getMetadata("important")->getOperand(0))->getString();
```

However, "add info" is printed after running the pass.

Second, it seems that the transformations are not applied on the .bc of the target program.
The Test1.bc (clean) and Test2.bc (transformation applied) are the same. I just have

```
using namespace llvm;

namespace {
  struct metadata : public FunctionPass {
    const Function *F;
    static char ID; // Pass identifcation, replacement for typeid
    metadata() : FunctionPass(ID) {
      //initializeMemDepPrinterPass(*PassRegistry::getPassRegistry());
    }
    virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F);
    virtual void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const {
      AU.setPreservesAll();
    }

   // virtual void releaseMemory() {
    //  F = 0;
   // }
  };
}

char metadata::ID = 0;

static RegisterPass<metadata> X("my-metadata", "Adding metadata", false, true);
```

at the beginning of my transformation pass. Please tell me how can I add metadata persistently.

Thank you for your answers !

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but just a comment: if you want to pass information from one LLVM pass to another, you don't need to use metadata, you can just add a dependency from the later pass to the earlier pass, and directly use its data - [read more about pass interaction on the LLVM manual](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#specifying-interactions-between-passes). Metadata is useful for other things, for example passing information from the frontend to the passes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue of interactions between passes (as raised by Oak's comments) nonwithstanding, it's not hard to write a pass that actually modifies the module by adding metadata. Here's a (basic-block, for easier writing) pass that adds the same metadata to each instruction it encounters. If you dump the module before and after running this pass, you will see that the module is indeed modified:

```
class MyBBPass : public BasicBlockPass {
public:
    static char ID;

    MyBBPass()
        : BasicBlockPass(ID)
    {}

    virtual bool runOnBasicBlock(BasicBlock &BB) {
        Value *A[] = {MDString::get(getGlobalContext(), "thing")};
        MDNode *Node = MDNode::get(getGlobalContext(), A);
        for (BasicBlock::iterator ii = BB.begin(), ii_e = BB.end();
             ii != ii_e; ++ii) {
            ii->setMetadata("md", Node);
        }

        return true;
    }
};

char MyBBPass::ID = 0;
```

Note that the `run***` method returns `true` to signal to the pass manager that the basic block was indeed modified.